# marker image with constant height and width of container

Tags: html, css

I have got a menu list:

```
<ul>
  <li class="marked">First item</li>
  <li>Second much longer than first item</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to have an image marker on top of item.marked which `width` will be 100% of text width. The image must stretch so it will be completely visible. `Height` is constant.

Can this be done with `CSS` and `IE` compatibility?

Comment: What kind of IE compatibility are you looking for? For IE9 and other browsers it can be done without any JavaScript. For IE8 and IE7, it can be done without JavaScript, but the behaviour won't be persistent (that is, your selected item stays selected *only* until you click somewhere else on the page).

Comment: is "selected" class a special class? it sholud not change. i am changing the class name to not cause any confussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .selected {
       background:url("example.png") no-repeat 0 100%;
    }
 </style>
```

Comment: is there any way to use it in ie8 ?

Answer (score 0):

Solutions for changing background of list item (can be adapted to change an image):

**1.** CSS-only, persistent, works for current versions of browsers (doesn't work for IE8 and older) - [**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3386325).

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="s" id="o1" checked>
        <label for="o1">First item</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="s" id="o2">
        <label for="o2">Second much longer than first item</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
ul input[type=radio] {
    display: none;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
    background: lightblue;
}
```

If you want to have an image (with img tag) above the selected items, then you can adapt it like in [**this demo**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3386435).

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="s" id="o1" checked>
        <label for="o1">First item
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/Supernumerary_rainbow_03_contrast.jpg">
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="s" id="o2">
        <label for="o2">Second much longer than first item
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/Supernumerary_rainbow_03_contrast.jpg">
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And add the following CSS:

```
label img {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label img {
    display: block;
}
```

If you don't want to do it with an `img` tag, then you can use a `background-image` on a pseudo-element and set the `background-size` to `100% 100%`, like in [**this demo**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3386462). The HTML is the same as in the first demo and you need to also have this in the CSS:

```
label {
    position: relative;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label:after {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/Supernumerary_rainbow_03_contrast.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    content: '';
}
```

**2.** CSS-only, not persistent (list item does not stay selected when you click somewhere else on the page), works for IE8 (and also IE7, but you have to hover off the text to see the change) - [**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3386358).

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">First item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Second much longer than first item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
a:active, a:focus {
    outline: none;
    background: lightblue;
}
```